# load a gcloud createReadStream into a variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I'm using the nodejs API for cloud storage

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node

I struggle in find a way to load a file as a string using the createReadStream().

There is an example on how to pipe the file and write in the local environment, but I'd prefer to just load it into a variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For future reference, This how I solved it. Fetching data from the buffer continuously.

```
var gcloud = require("gcloud")({ /* credentials. */ });
var cloudstorage = gcloud.storage();
var myTextFile = cloudstorage.file('your-file.txt');

var fileContents = new Buffer('');

myTextFile.createReadStream()
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    fileContents = Buffer.concat([fileContents, chunk]);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // `fileContents` is ready
  });
```

The gCloud 3rd party libraries team generously agree in adding a new methods for simplify the request:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/pull/381

Update:

The function is now available in the gcloud library.

Comment: I think it's 'end', not 'complete'

Comment: Download function on that link has been implemented now, see https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File ...